# test command complains "too many arguments"

Tags: shell, double-quotes

The error message is the one in the title of this question.
It looks like the problem is inside `[ ]`, but I'm not sure.

What this program aims to do is to take two parameters (directory and extension) and delete all files with that extension in that directory:

```
count=0
for i in $1/*.$2 ; do
       if [ -s $i ]
                then rm $i
                echo "$i deleted"
        fi
done
```

Comment: Did you try `if [ -s "$1" ]` and `rm "$i"`?

Comment: You had better make sure that `$1` and `$2` have values otherwise your script will execute `rm /*.` which could be very bad!

Comment: Your question and your English are fine (kudos for the effort and proper code formatting); my only suggestion is to make the title more descriptive and put the error message [also] in the question body.

Comment: @RedCricket: That's a good point in general (validating arguments); luckily, in this particular case `/*.` will probably not do much harm, because it would only try to delete files (in the root directory) with names ending in `.`, which is rare. (and would also fail with a permissions error unless you're running as root).

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help. It's apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lurker's comment provides the crucial pointer: **double-quoting is needed for variable references such as `$i` to be expanded to their value without further interpretation.**

Some rules of thumb for [POSIX-compatible, Bourne-like] shell programming:

- **Always *double-quote* variable references to prevent interpretation of their value by the shell** (such as splitting the value into multiple tokens and interpreting the value as a glob (filename pattern)); e.g., a variable reference such as `"$i"`.

  - Presumably, your problem was that `$i`'s value contained whitespace, and since `$i` was unquoted, the shell split the value into *multiple* tokens, resulting in a syntax error, because the `-s` operator only accepts a *single* argument.

- Conversely, **only use *unquoted* strings and variable references if you *explicitly want the shell to interpret the value***; e.g., the `*` in a glob such as `*.txt`, because it is unquoted, is treated as a wildcard character.

  - Note that your glob, `$1/*.$2`, however, is problematic, because it still contains unquoted variable references - see next point.

- **A *single* string can (and may need to) MIX the two approaches**:

  - QUOTE the parts you want UN-interpreted (*double*-quote strings containing variable references and similar expressions, *single*-quote string literals).
  - LEAVE UNQUOTED the parts you want INTERPRETED, such as wildcards for globbing (pathname expansions.
  - Thus, the robust version of your glob is as follows: `"$1"/*."$2"` - with the variable references double-quoted, but the wildcard character (`*`) unquoted.

    - (This could also be written as `"$1/"*".$2"` to leave only the globbing character unquoted, but I've chosen to double-quote the parameter references individually for clarity; since, `/` and `.` are not subject to interpretation by the shell, either form will work.)

If we put it all together:

```
for i in "$1"/*."$2" ; do
   if [ -s "$i" ]; then
      rm "$i"
      echo "$i deleted"
   fi
done
```

---

- The shared language that POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` speak is defined here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html
- However, since this is an *abstract* specification, you're better off finding materials for the *specific* shell you use, such as `bash`.

Comment: Thanks man for taking the time of answering. Your effort has been of useful value.

Comment: @user3851329: I'm glad to hear it; my pleasure.